# Facebook didn't crawl the og:image when using sharethis

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, sharethis

I have used sharethis plugin in my website. When I shared a particular page it does not crawl the correct image in the share popup window. But after sharing it to the facebook, I can see the correct image. It happens for a particular page only.

I have checked the `og:image` property and the image meets all its requirement. The dimension of the image is 362x550. I have no idea why it doesn't crawl the image.

Please anyone assist me to get resolve this issue.

Here is the [link](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fshar.es%2F1rC1nM&t=Women%20Winners) I shared via *sharethis*.

Page Link:
https://www.getcensored.com/m/photocontest/view/Kassie-Tocko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you exactly solution, but will try to give you at least some direction.

So what I observed with FB debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

1. Put initial link https://www.getcensored.com/m/photocontest/view/Kassie-Tocko#st_refDomain=&st_refQuery= and you will see that FB will see your og:image tag
2. Put some other anchor https://www.getcensored.com/m/photocontest/view/Kassie-Tocko#test1 and click "Fetch new scrape information", you will see a message about parsing error, then try to fetch again and you will see og:image

Try repeat 2. several times with different anchors

I had a similar issue, but the problem was 301 redirect, but you don't have it. May be try disable https and test FB sharing via http, just for test. May be problem is with your SSL negotiation time. Some info related FB and SSL here http://www.webpagetest.org/forums/showthread.php?tid=11788

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing the URL to http:// and again changed it to https://

Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

For facebook to get to your image it needs the total url to your image and not the relative url..

Example of tht url that facebook expects to be in its og:image tag content :

```
http://www.exmaple.com/images/img1.png
```

I hope this helps you.